# How to add a generic parameter to a class generated by JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, maven, generics, jaxb2

I'm using maven-jaxb2-plugin and jaxb2-basics plugin to generate java classes from a XSD schema.

I need to make some of those generated classes implement a custom interface:

```
public interface MyInterface<O extends MyObject> {

    O getO();
    O setO(O myObject);

}
```

So I'm using the inheritance plugin, configured in a bindings file:

```
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='MyXmlType']">
    <inheritance:implements>com.example.MyInterface</inheritance:implements>
</jxb:bindings>
```

How can I specify the type of the generic parameter in the implementing class (MyXmlType)? Is there an already existing plugin?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's pretty simple.

Just write the desired generic type in the binding.

```
<jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='MyXmlType']">
    <inheritance:implements>com.example.MyInterface&lt;CustomMyObject&gt;</inheritance:implements>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Comment: When I try this, I get "import com.example.MyInterface<CustomMyObject>;" which of course doesn't compile. Suggestions?

Comment: @Rob it looks like the latest version of basics supports this, and correctly adds the `import fm.aaia.pies.xml.v6.DigitalFileInformationBase;`  but does the `public class DigitalFileInformation implements DigitalFileInformationBase<DigitalFileInformation>`

Comment: @ericpeters Awesome! Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: Actually you can also use FQCN as generic parameter:
`... <inheritance:implements>com.example.MyInterface&lt;com.other.example2.CustomMyObject&gt;</inheritance:implements>...`